# javascript new Date() error

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string: `Aug. 1, 2014`

when I perform a

```
var test_string = 'Aug. 1, 2014';
var test = new Date(test_string);
```

this produced an invalid date error.

```
    var date_year = new Date(Date.parse(test_string)).getFullYear(),
        date_month = new Date(Date.parse(test_string)).getMonth()+1,
        date_day = new Date(Date.parse(test_string)).getDate();
    new_date = new Date(date_year,date_month,date_day);
```

also produces an error...I think I am following the correct mdn format as specified here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: You have a conflict: `test_string` in the `Date()` argument, yet `date_string` is what you created. Notice `test_` vs. `date_`.

Comment: To avoid confusing with local properties (month language, ...), you should use format like yyyy-mmm-ddd

Comment: I misstyped it here, but it wasn't misstyped in my actual code. just corrected the code here

Comment: peeps - why is this question off topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the period "." from the end of Aug. It parses correctly.  Try:

```
var test_string = 'Aug 1, 2014';
var test = new Date(test_string);
```

Look here for acceptable date strings:

[RFC 2822 Page 14](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)

Comment: Yes this definitely was the issue. Spent 2 hours debugging this period problem. No wonder I just got this bug recently when the month turned august.